# JQuery UI AutoComplete - can't get data typed in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've changed the standard method of Jquery UI autocomplete to use POST instead of GET:

```
$(function () {
    var data = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'location=' + data;

    $(".suggest_locations").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: response
            })
        },
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 0,
        autoFocus: true
    });
});
```

But "data" is always empty, no matter what I write in the input field.

I'm using an external file called ajax.php to get all saved locations from a database, but it'll show always all locations available, because "data" doesn't read what I'm typing in the input field.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: If your file is external make sure its accessible via POST, try using fiddler and see what is actually going on with the request.
Most common mistake is that your post request is being ignored by your php file.

Comment: This is what I do all the time, but I guess there's something wrong with the javascript code or it has to be improved, because it seems he don't even read what I've typed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable data is not updated when you change the value of your input field, but only once: when the document is loaded.

Use this instead of your source option:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        type    : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data    : 'location=' + request.term,
        cache   : false,
        success : function(data) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. What does ".term" stands for?

Comment: `term` is the property of the `request` object that contains the current value of your input field. Dont know why they called it "term", "value" would make more sense to me lol.